# How to lock table in postgresql using spring

Tags: spring, postgresql, locking, mybatis

How to lock table in postgresql and spring and mybatis so that only one instance at a time can read that table and other instances wait. Only one read at a time is allowed from table when multiple instances are running

Comment: why would you care how many concurrent reads there are, none of them are going to change the data?

Comment: actually its a distributed system where two instances are running and i want that when first instance is accessing table then second instance is not allowed to read that table

Answer (score 0):

See: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html perhaps "advisory locks" also could be sufficient.